# Get page size without downloading

Tags: html, size

Although i don't think it's possible but is it a way to get a page size without downloading it?(it's seems silly but anyway i wanna ask it here)

you can curl a page and get it's size but i don't want to dl the page and also there is nothing interesting in the header with text/html.

Comment: Truly speaking you can't. Because you have no idea what the page's size is, unless you load it. Think of images, scripts, styles embedded on the page.

Comment: curl reads text and all it see is text if u wanna do that u should go into all links and resources one by one find out what is there size

Answer (score 4):

Query the `Content-Length` property from the page header.

As defined by [Section 14.13 of the Hypertext Transfer Protocol Documentation](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13).

Comment: Well I stand corrected. Check my comment on the question. I now see that curl too downloads just the page of size specified by Content-Length. It doesn't load the images, scripts, styles etc. right? If so, yeah Content-Length should be it.

Comment: it works for other mime/types except text/html cause info is in the header

Comment: @goldenparrot how u get the text size of the page all i get is -1

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`HEAD`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) HTTP method instead of `GET`:

> The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT return a message-body in the response. The metainformation contained in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical to the information sent in response to a GET request. **This method can be used for obtaining metainformation about the entity implied by the request without transferring the entity-body itself.**

Comment: it's better to use get_headers() php function instead of curl because it's so much faster. anyway i can't see content-lengeth using head method for text/html mime type

Comment: i used curl with curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'HEAD') also neither way works

Answer (score 0):

Even making a HEAD request doesn't guaranty u will get content-length in the output. check it for yourself:

```
stream_context_set_default(
    array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'HEAD'
        )
    )
);

var_dump(get_headers("http://www.stackoverflow.com", 1));
var_dump(get_headers("http://www.google.com", 1));
var_dump(get_headers("http://php.net/", 1));
```

I think the best option is still to go and dl the page using curl and then see what's the size(pure text) of the page